# cordova index.html file path for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

I've got a cordova project and need to authorise a google maps API call from our index.html page. I've successfully done this for Android by adding "file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html" to our authorised URLs. However I can't seem to get the file path right for our iOS build. The index.html is in a www/default folder, so I tried file:///www/default/index.html however this doesn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you're searching:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"];
```